# How can I capture File directory from edit control(textbox)

Tags: c++

so I am new to the whole c++ windows API. I'm creating a simple dialogbox in which the user types in a directory into a textbox for a time file which has already been created. the program will then read the file and display the time in another edit control. Im having a few problems making the directory entered the parameter for CreateFile(). If I hard code the directory in, the program will work correctly. But I cant figure out how to take the textbox data and plug it into the CreateFile() function. if this doesn't make sense i can try an explain differently. Ive searched an can't seem to find anything.

Thanks

for example: 
if the user types `c:\test\time.txt`  into the text box I want `"c:\test\time.txt"` to be the put into CreateFile();

```
CHAR temp[20] = "";
HANDLE hFile;
GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_TEXTIN, temp, 20);//IDC_TEXTIN is name of edit control
//open file
hFile = CreateFile(
    temp,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,                      // no sharing 
    NULL,                   // no security
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL                    // no template
);
```

Comment: Is your file name really shorter than 20 characters?

Comment: Use the debugger to see what you get in the temp variable. We can't help you much without knowing some facts about what is wrong.